How to Effectively Migrate Legacy ASP.NET WebForms to Blazor with Session Sharing?
I'm currently in the middle of a project where we're migrating our old ASP.NET WebForms (VB.NET) ecommerce site to a new Blazor (ASP.NET Core 7.0) application. We're using an incremental migration approach, so we'll have both the old and new applications running in parallel until we complete the migration.
I've run into a few challenges and I'm hoping to get some advice from those who might have tackled similar projects:
Session Management: Our current application uses sessions extensively (e.g., Session("OrderId")). Has anyone successfully shared session data between ASP.NET WebForms and Blazor? Any tips on using Redis or SQL Server for this purpose?
Incremental Migration Strategy: What are some best practices or potential pitfalls to watch out for with an incremental migration? How can we keep the data consistent and the user experience smooth during this process?
Performance Optimization: What should we keep in mind to ensure good performance in the new Blazor app? Any advice on optimizing database access, response times, and overall scalability?
Security: As we transition to Blazor, what security measures should we focus on to ensure our new application meets modern standards?
Testing and QA: What are effective strategies for testing during this migration? How do we make sure both the old and new systems work well together and provide a seamless user experience?
Our business application is critical for our ecommerce operations, so we need to get this right. Any insights, tips, or resources you could share would be greatly appreciated!
